# Display object datas in JSX

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript

I have this Object in my state :
[console.log(state)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Jq8w.png)

I created a component to render a card for each entry in this object (which has under object)

I have tried everything, but I always get an error. Here is my last attempt :

```
import { useState } from "react"

export default function Categories(props: any) {
    const [listOfCategories, setListOfCategories] = useState(props.datas.categories)

    console.log(listOfCategories)
    return (
        <>
            {listOfCategories.map(category => {
                return (
                    <div key={category} className="relative flex flex-wrap h-96 my-20">
                        <div className="absolute right-0 top-0 h-full">
                            <img className="rounded-lg max-w-full h-96" src="https://double-you-design.fr/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/dummy-post-horisontal.jpg" alt="" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="absolute -bottom-10 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-lg w-7/12 h-48 p-8">
                            <p key={category}>{category}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })
            }
        </>
    )
}
```

the error is : listOfCategories.map is not a function.

My question is : What is the simplest method to do this ?
Do you have a recommandation, or an example ?

I am working with TypeScript.

Thank you very much !

Comment: That's an object, `map` is a function on arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `.map` on an object because it is a method of Array.

You could do it with [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) like so:

```
import { useState } from "react"

export default function Categories(props: any) {
    const [listOfCategories, setListOfCategories] = useState(props.datas.categories)

    console.log(listOfCategories)
    return (
        <>
            {Object.keys(listOfCategories).map((key, ind) => {
                return (
                    <div key={ind} className="relative flex flex-wrap h-96 my-20">
                        <div className="absolute right-0 top-0 h-full">
                            <img className="rounded-lg max-w-full h-96" src="https://double-you-design.fr/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/dummy-post-horisontal.jpg" alt="" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="absolute -bottom-10 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-lg w-7/12 h-48 p-8">
                            <p key={ind}>{listOfCategories[key].category}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })
            }
        </>
    )
}
```

Here is a simple runnable example to illustrate:

```js
var obby = { a: { category: 'Estimation' }, b: { category: 'Prospection' } }
const categories = Object.keys(obby).map(key => obby[key].category)
console.log(categories)
```

Another option would be to change your data structure so that you have an array of objects instead of an object of objects - if you have control over that data structure. If not, you could first convert the object to an array.

```js
const obby = { estimate: { category: 'Estimation' }, prospecting: { category: 'Prospection' } }
const arr = Object.values(obby)
const categories = arr.map(val => val.category)
console.log(categories)
```

Above method in your code:

```
import { useState } from "react"

export default function Categories(props: any) {
    const [listOfCategories, setListOfCategories] = useState(props.datas.categories)

    const listOfCategoriesArray  = Object.values(listOfCategories)
    return (
        <>
            {listOfCategoriesArray.map((item, ind) => {
                return (
                    <div key={ind} className="relative flex flex-wrap h-96 my-20">
                        <div className="absolute right-0 top-0 h-full">
                            <img className="rounded-lg max-w-full h-96" src="https://double-you-design.fr/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/dummy-post-horisontal.jpg" alt="" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="absolute -bottom-10 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-lg w-7/12 h-48 p-8">
                            <p key={ind}>{item.category}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })
            }
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The problem is, how can i get the Object values inside these key ?

Comment: @Joh - My examples show the use of the values. In the first example, I am getting the value of the category attribute of the object with `{listOfCategories[key].category}` so `listofCategories[key]` is your object and you can reference any of it's properties as usual.
In the second example, the object is referenced from `item` so the category value is `item.category`.